# Storing pygame surface objects

Tags: python, pygame

I have created 10 `surface` objects in pygame using `subsurface`. I am using them to save as `jpg`'s.

How can use an `array` or a list to store them and using the `array` or `list` later with indexing? It would be easy way to access.

Comment: Do you mean save them to the disk, or save them in the memory?

Comment: saving them in memory to access them later on

Comment: like when i want to use surface1 i can go like this name[0]

Answer (score 0):

Just create a list, like

```
images = [surface1, surface2, surface3, surface4 ...etc... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on sloth's answer, you can do this:

```
names = "image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg"
surfaces = []
for name in names:
    surfaces.append(pygame.image.load(name).convert())
```

Then you can access them as surface[0], surface[1] and so on.

You may want to read up on lists and for loops. (Really just repeat the first few chapters of whatever introductory book you're reading.)

Comment: That's been helpful. Thank you.